# Is there any formula or trick to count how many times a statement inside a nested loop gets executed?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, loops

I am modifying a software which is for trash collection. While reading the code, I asked myself is there any formula or trick to quickly calculate the number of time the statement gets executed inside the nested loop rather than doing it manually in head. Here's the kinda pseudo code for this----

```
for(i=1; i<=9;i++)
{
   sum = 0;
   for(j=i; j<=N && sum<=10; j++)
      sum = sum + arr[j] //any quick trick to calculate it's number of execution
}
```

Comment: In this situation, it will highly depend on the content of the array, due to sum<=10 predicate. You can estimate worst and best case scenarios. But for real-world execution, you need to run it and measure it.

Comment: By introducing a counter variable? Or do you mean "beforehand", by analysing the code?

Comment: @DocBrown I mean beforehand by analysing the code

Comment: Do you know about *computational complexity* ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I know...... But here I am not looking for the Big O..... All I am wondering is there any trick to calculate the number of execution of a statement.

Comment: OK.  Which takes us back to @Euphoric's comment.

Comment: @AKdeBerg the trick is that you have to know the values that would be used for the conditions. If you know then you can just compute this manually on a piece of paper or in your head.

Comment: @AKdeBerg: and how do you expect this to be possible without knowing the content of the array `arr` beforehand?

Comment: @DocBrown Well, I know the content of the array.. X[] = {11,1,2,1,1,5,10,2,3}.... index of first element is 1.

Comment: @VLAZ so there's no way to do it using formula rather than multiplying the iteration of outer and inner loop?

Comment: @AKdeBerg you can *derive* a formula. There is no generic one that I know of...but then again, I suppose somebody with a stronger compsci and/or maths backgroung might have one. Still, it'd be quite generic and not something you can easily calculate, I'd assume.

Comment: In the general case, this is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: *"rather than multiplying the iteration of outer and inner loop"* - makes no sense, the number of "inner loop" iterations is not a constant, so what do you want to multiply here?

Comment: Quick trick eh?  Set N to 0 and it executes no times : ) Seriously the quickest way to calculate this is to write a program that calculates this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another variable  like this to find out how many time loop is executed or what is the current number of a loop being  executing in debug :

```
int count = 0;

for(i=1; i<=9;i++)
{
   sum = 0;
   for(j=i; j<=N && sum<=10; j++)
    {
      sum = sum + arr[j] //any quick trick to calculate it's number of execution
      count++;
    }
}
```